# Basic Auth doesn't work in kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, pypiserver

I have created pypiserver in kubernetes cluster, I have used https://hub.docker.com/r/pypiserver/pypiserver docker image. I need to create basic auth for the server which I created. I used this method https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pypiserver
  labels:
    app: pypiserver
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: secret
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required - ok"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: pypiservice
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: secret-tls
```

But my host name would be "www.example.com/8080" and I don't see ingress has any pod in kubernetes cluster. Ingress is running fine but I don't get auth for this host. (And also I have http://IP adress:8080 which I converted to domain through cloudflare)

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've reproduced your case and it looks like indeed there are some problems with `basic auth` in nginx ingress controller (at least in some versions). I found a few similar issues on github https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3480 If I manage to make it work ( I'm currently testing it on my GKE cluster ) I'll let you know and share my solution.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly what is your **nginx ingress controller** version, but I can share what worked for me. I've reproduced it on my GKE **cluster**.

I installed my nginx ingress controller following [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) guide. Basically it came down to running the following commands:

> If you're using GKE you need to initialize your user as a
>   cluster-admin with the following command:
>
> ```
> kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
>   --clusterrole cluster-admin \
>   --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
> ```
>
> The following Mandatory Command is required for all deployments.
>
> ```
> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.27.1/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
> ```

I'm using 1.13 version on my GKE so this tip is also applied in my case:

> Tip
>
> If you are using a Kubernetes version previous to `1.14`, you need to
>   change `kubernetes.io/os` to `beta.kubernetes.io/os` at line 217 of
>   `mandatory.yaml`, see Labels details.

But I dealt with it quite differently. Basically you need your `Nodes` to have `kubernetes.io/os=linux` label so you can simply label them. Following command will do the job:

```
kubectl label node --all kubernetes.io/os=linux
```

Then we're heading to [Provider Specific Steps](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#provider-specific-steps) which in case of [GKE](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke) came down to applying the following `yaml`:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.27.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml
```

Then you may want to [verify](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#verify-installation) your installation:

> To check if the ingress controller pods have started, run the
>   following command:
>
> ```
> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -l app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx --watch
> ```

or simply run:

```
kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
```

It will also tell you if all the required resorces are properly deployed.

Next we need to write our ingress (ingress object/resource) containing `basic-auth` related `annotations`. I was following [same tutorial](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/) as mentioned in your question.

First we need to create our `auth` file containing `username` and hashed `password`:

```
$ htpasswd -c auth foo
New password: <bar>
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user foo
```

Once we have it, we need to create a `Secret` object which then we'll use in our ingress:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=auth
secret "basic-auth" created
```

Once it is created we can check if everything went well:

```
$ kubectl get secret basic-auth -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  auth: Zm9vOiRhcHIxJE9GRzNYeWJwJGNrTDBGSERBa29YWUlsSDkuY3lzVDAK
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: basic-auth
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
```

Alright, so far so good...

Then we need to create our `ingress resource/object`.

My `ingress-with-auth.yaml` file looks slightly different than the one in [the instruction](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/), namely I just added `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` to make sure my **nginx ingress controller** is used rather than built-in GKE solution:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-with-auth
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # type of authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    # name of the secret that contains the user/password definitions
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    # message to display with an appropriate context why the authentication is required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - foo'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: pypiserver
          servicePort: 80
```

In your example you may need to add `nginx` prefix in your `basic-auth` related annotations:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: secret
ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required - ok"
```

so it looks like this:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: secret
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required - ok"
```

First I used the address listed in my ingress resource (it doesn't appear there any more once I added `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` annotation in my `ingress` definition:

```
$ kubectl get ingress 
NAME                HOSTS         ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress-with-auth   foo.bar.com             80      117m
```

When I tried to access `pypi-server` using this IP it brought me directly to the page without a need of any authentication. But it looks like if you didn't define proper ingress class, the default is used instead so in practice your `ingress` definition with `auth-basic` details isn't taken into consideration and isn't passed to the **nginx ingress controller** we installed in one of the previous steps.

So what IP address should be used to access your app ? Run the following command which will show you both `CLUSTER-IP` (can be accessed within your cluster from any `Pod` or `Node`) and `EXTERNAL-IP` of your **nginx ingress controller**:

```
$ kubectl get service --namespace ingress-nginx 
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.0.3.220   35.111.112.113   80:30452/TCP,443:30006/TCP   18h
```

You can basically host many different websites in your cluster and all of them will be available through this IP. All of them can be available on default `http 80` port (or `https 443` in your case). The only difference between them will be the `hostname` that you pass in `http` header of your `http request`.

Since I don't have a domain pointing to this external IP address and can't simply access my website by going to `http://foo.bar.com` I need to pass somehow the `hostname` I'm requesting from `35.111.112.113` address. It can be done in a few ways:

I installed in my **Google Chrome browser** [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) extension which allows me to modify my http request headers and set the `hostname` I'm requestig to any value I want.

You can do it also using `curl` as follows:

```
curl -v http://35.111.112.113 -H 'Host: foo.bar.com' -u 'foo:bar'
```

You should be prompted for authentication.

If you don't provide `-u username:password` flag you should get `401 Authorization Required`.

Basically hat's all.

Let me know if it helped you. Don't hesitate to ask additional questions if something isn't completely clear.

One more thing. If something still doesn't work you may start from attaching to your **nginx ingress controller** `Pod` (check your `Pod` name first by running `kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx`):

```
kubectl exec -ti -n ingress-nginx nginx-ingress-controller-pod /bin/bash
```

and checking the content of your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. Look for `foo.bar.com` (or in your case `example.com`). It should contain similar lines:

```
auth_basic "Authentication Required - foo";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/ingress-controller/auth/default-ingress-with-auth.passwd;
```

Then check if the file is present in the indicated location `/etc/ingress-controller/auth/default-ingress-with-auth.passwd`.

One note to your `Service` definition. The fact that `pypiserver` container exposes specifically port 8080 doesn't mean that you need to use this port when accessing it via ingress. In `Service` definition the port exposed by the `Container` is called `targetPort`. You need to specify it when defining your `Service` but `Service` itself can expose completely different port. I defined my `Service` using following command:

```
kubectl expose deployment pypiserver --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --target-port=8080
```

Note that the `type` should be set to `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`. Then in your ingress definition you don't have to use `8080` but `80` which is the port exposed by your `pypiserver` `Service`. Note that there is `servicePort: 80` in my `ingress object/resource` definition. Your `example.com` domain in **cloudflare** should point with it's `A record` to your `nginx ingress controller` `LoadBalancer` `Service` IP (`kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx`) without specifying any ports.

Comment: In my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` there is no basic auth related configurations on my Server definition. But when verifiying with a `kubectl describe ingress -A` all annotations are correct (nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/*). Is this related to the same issue (works without basic auth but with it yields a 503 error) or some other configuration error? Thanks.

Comment: I found my error, I created a file named "basic-auth" instead of "auth" to create the secret from it. Thanks.

Comment: Another tip: ensure, that secret and ingress-ngnix is in the same namespace